# Google Cloud Build stuck on "Creating an optimized production build..."

Tags: reactjs, docker, google-cloud-platform, create-react-app

I am trying to deploy our React app using Google Cloud Platform.
I followed [this YouTube video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GIM5irN4Ix0), and it worked well for a simple test React project.
But when I applied it to our source code, the build failed with the following messages.

[image: Error1]

So I increased the Memory from 512 MB to 32GB.
But at that time the build was stuck on  " Creating an optimized production build...".

[image: Stuck]

At local the production build of our React app finishes in 10min.

This is a Docker file.

```
FROM node:16.20.1-alpine

RUN echo "creating api, client folder"
WORKDIR /app

RUN mkdir /app/api
RUN mkdir /app/api/build
RUN mkdir /app/client

RUN echo "copying package.json files"

COPY package.json /app/
COPY ./api/package.json /app/api/
COPY ./api/yarn.lock /app/api/
COPY ./client/package.json /app/client/
COPY ./client/yarn.lock /app/client/

RUN echo "install node modules"

WORKDIR /app
RUN yarn install

WORKDIR /app/api
RUN yarn install

WORKDIR /app/client
RUN yarn install

RUN echo "copy other files"

COPY . /app/

RUN echo "build client"

WORKDIR /app/client
RUN yarn build

RUN echo "copy build content"
RUN mv /app/client/build/* /app/api/build

EXPOSE 3000

CMD ["/app/api/node_modules/.bin/ts-node", "/app/api/server.ts"]
```

Thank you.